# Javascript library for multiple factor legend plot

Tags: javascript, legend, plotly, canvasjs

I am trying to draw a plot with multiple factors. I hope these different factors are distinguished by color, size, and shape of the scatter. An example of this kind of plot is here [https://github.com/slfan2013/tempPlot/blob/master/Rplot.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rc8Gh.png).

I'd like to use a javascript library to draw a similar plot. I usually use [plotly.js](https://plot.ly/javascript/) to draw plots. But I think plotly can only handle one factor at a time (different colors). My question is **can plotly handle multiple (nested) factors in one single plot (like color, size, and shape)?** If not, if there is any javascript library can achieve these? How about CanvasJS?

**#### EDIT.**

I understand how to draw scatter with different color and different size (shape, etc) on the same plot. I just would like to have a multiple-factor legend on the plot, so that if I click "red", for example, then the red scatters would hide no matter what size it is AND if I click size "big", big scatters would hide no matter what color it is.

Thanks!

Comment: anyone cares to tell me the reason of downvoting?

Comment: Probably because of asking for a library and no code with a specific problem.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters I dunno. Clearly this is not a code related question. I googled "JavaScript stack exchange" and this site is the first search result. That's why I asked here. Thx answering though.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in CanvasJS using scatter chart and by controlling markerType and markerSize. Check the example shown below.

Refer these pages for markerType and markerSize.

http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/markertype/

http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/markersize/

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
{
 title: {
  text: "Scatter Chart with Different Marker Types"
 },
 legend: {
      horizontalAlign: "right",
      verticalAlign: "center"
 },
 data: [
 {
  type: "scatter",
  showInLegend: true,
  legendText: "Circle",
  dataPoints: [
   { x: 1, y: 91, markerSize: 10 },
   { x: 2, y: 75, markerSize: 20 },
   { x: 3, y: 70, markerSize: 30 },
   { x: 4, y: 85, markerSize: 40 },
   { x: 5, y: 75, markerSize: 50 }   
  ]
 },
 {
  type: "scatter",
  markerType: "square", //default "circle"
  showInLegend: true,
  legendText: "Square",
  dataPoints: [
   { x: 1, y: 71, markerSize: 10 },
   { x: 2, y: 55, markerSize: 20 },
   { x: 3, y: 50, markerSize: 30 },
   { x: 4, y: 65, markerSize: 40 },
   { x: 5, y: 55, markerSize: 50 }   
  ]
 },
 {
  type: "scatter",
  markerType: "triangle",
  showInLegend: true,
  legendText: "Triangle",
  dataPoints: [
   { x: 1, y: 51, markerSize: 10 },
   { x: 2, y: 35, markerSize: 20 },
   { x: 3, y: 30, markerSize: 30 },
   { x: 4, y: 45, markerSize: 40 },
   { x: 5, y: 35, markerSize: 50 }
  ]
 },
 {
  type: "scatter",
  markerType: "cross",
  showInLegend: true,
  legendText: "Cross",
  dataPoints: [
   { x: 1, y: 31, markerSize: 10 },
   { x: 2, y: 15, markerSize: 20 },
   { x: 3, y: 10, markerSize: 30 },
   { x: 4, y: 25, markerSize: 40 },
   { x: 5, y: 15, markerSize: 50 }
  ]
 }
 ]
});

chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Vishwas R for your very nice example. However, it does not have a two-factor legend, color and size.  If it is possible to have multi-factor legend, if I click size "big", then big scatters would hide, no matter what shape it is.

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to define multiple traces and set the parameters for each trace individually.

- `trace0` is just the default settings
- `trace1` has a custom color
- `trace2` has a custom color and custom size
- `trace3` has a custom color, custom size and custom symbol

```js
var trace0 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3], 
  y: [1, 2, 3], 
  type: 'scatter', 
  mode:'markers'};
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3], 
  y: [2, 1.8, 1], 
  type: 'scatter', 
  mode:'markers', 
  marker: {
    color: 'red'
  }};
var trace2 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3], 
  y: [2.8, 2.3, 1.2], 
  type: 'scatter', 
  mode:'markers', 
  marker: {
    color: 'green', 
    size: [10, 15, 20]
  }};
var trace3 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3], 
  y: [3, 2.5, 1], 
  type: 'scatter', 
  mode:'markers', 
  marker: {
    color: 'pink', 
    size: [10, 15, 20], 
    symbol: 303
  }};

Plotly.plot('myDiv', [trace0, trace1, trace2, trace3])
```

```html
<div id='myDiv'></div>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. For your example, the legend is just coloring differences but not sizing. Is there's a way for nesting factors? One factor for coloring, another factor for sizing?

Comment: @user7117436: As far as I know Plotly does not support this feature directly, https://community.plot.ly/t/possible-to-have-nested-or-hierarchical-legends/2376/2